# SFMC - Getting content builder template last modified date using QUERY or SSJS

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to get the last modification date of a template that lives under content builder in salesforce marketing cloud. Is it possible to get it using SSJS or QUERY at all? The SSJS will be part of automation on SFMC

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible via REST API using a filter: [Advanced Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/assetAdvancedQuery.html)

The `modifiedDate` property is listed in the [Attribute List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/asset-attribute-list.html) as retreiveable.